# AJAX form submission - No data returned

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Form:

```
<form action="" id="register" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="eg. John">
    <input type="text" placeholder="eg. Appleseed">
    <input type="text" placeholder="youremail@domain.com">
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('form#register').on('submit',function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'submit.php',
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        context: this,
        data : $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(json) {
            console.log("json: " + json);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

PHP:

```
$formData = json_encode($_POST);
echo print_r($formData,1);
```

... after filling the form and hitting submit, it does submit the form without an error, but the data returned (JSON) is empty:

`json: []`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging. Look in the Net tab of your developer tools. Look at the request being sent to `submit.php`. Does it have the form data in it that you expect? Look at the response. Does it contain the data you expect?

Comment: Use the developer tools network tag. Check which data is submitted to the server and which data is returned from the server.

Comment: The only way I've been able to reproduce this is if there was no serializable data in the form (which you haven't shared with us) in the first place.

Comment: Network Tab in Chrome shows: `Request URL:http://localhost:5757/submit.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK`

Comment: `print_r` already echoes the content, but in any case it should be echoing the array and `1` (because echo print_r() evaluates to true, as far as I know). Can you please provide us your html code? also, what happens if you set `dataType: "json"`? (it should just parse the result as a json object, what is strange is that you are getting an empty response, it looks like $_POST is either empty or not properly set)

Comment: I've updated the description with the form HTML just incase I'm doing something wrong there.

Comment: Oh, try setting the **name** attributes too to your HTML tags!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are not using `name` attribute in your fields

```
serialize()
```

Requires `name` field in your form

Answer (score 2):

1:-

`$formData = json_encode($_POST);
echo print_r($formData,1);`

should be :-

```
$formData = json_encode($_POST);
echo $formData;
```

2.You are not having `name` attribute in your form fields. please provide that otherwise `serialize()` will not work correctly.

Comment: what is the diference from returning the data and echoing it?

Comment: he used both `echo and print_r` both together which is not correct